# Can you recommend a module for localization using one ore two video cameras?

Tags: ros, localization, navigation, video

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The title says all - I've one (or two cameras, maybe handy for stereo vision) which I would like to use for localization. Data from odometry is here, too.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/120406/can-you-recommend-a-module-for-localization-using-one-ore-two-video-cameras?/) by [mifritscher](https://answers.ros.org/users/3945/mifritscher/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2014-01-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'll suggest [PTAM](http://wiki.ros.org/ethzasl_ptam/ptam)

---

Originally posted by [Vikas](https://answers.ros.org/users/1768/vikas/) with karma: 106 on 2014-01-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mifritscher](https://answers.ros.org/users/3945/mifritscher/) on 2014-01-24**:
thanks for the hint - where can I find the sources for the modified packages? I can only find the original sources without the adaptions for ros...
EDIT: sorry, found it: https://github.com/ethz-asl/ethzasl_ptam

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you can use [viso2_ros](http://wiki.ros.org/viso2_ros)

---

Originally posted by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) with karma: 1769 on 2014-01-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mifritscher](https://answers.ros.org/users/3945/mifritscher/) on 2014-01-24**:
thanks!
But it seems that viso2 heavily depends on x86/x64 :-(
I first needed to disable the sse2 flag, but it also hard-includes files which are specific to sse2:
linaro@michis-cubietruck:~/ros_foreign_src/viso2/libviso2/libviso2$ make
[ 11%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/viso2.dir/src/demo.cpp.o
In file included from /home/linaro/ros_foreign_src/viso2/libviso2/libviso2/src/viso.h:26:0,
from /home/linaro/ros_foreign_src/viso2/libviso2/libviso2/src/viso_stereo.h:25,
from /home/linaro/ros_foreign_src/viso2/libviso2/libviso2/src/demo.cpp:34:
/home/linaro/ros_foreign_src/viso2/libviso2/libviso2/src/matcher.h:30:23: fatal error: emmintrin.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

But I'm working on arm.